# Facts about the tensor product

Tags: tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

I'm proving some statements about density operators, and would like to use two things. The problem is, that I'm not entirely sure they hold.

Let $V,\; W$ be finite dimensional, complex inner product spaces. The statements I want to use are:

(i) $\psi \in V\otimes W \; \Longrightarrow \; \exists \; v\in V, \; w\in W$ such that $\psi = v \otimes w.$

(ii) $\rho \in \text{End}(V\otimes W); \;\phi_1, \; \phi_2 \in \text{End}(V); \; \theta_1, \theta_2 \in \text{End} (W)$ such that $\psi = \phi_1 \otimes \theta_1 = \phi_2 \otimes \theta_2$ $ \Longrightarrow \; \phi_1 = \phi_ 2,\; \theta_1 = \theta_2$.

Does somebody know if these two are true?

Comment: Consider $\mathbb R^2$ with the standard basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$. There's no way to write $e_1 \otimes e_2 + e_2 \otimes e_1$ in the way you want to in (i).

Answer (score 1):

Both are false as stated.

1. The set $\{ v \otimes w : v \in V, w \in W \}$ is not even a vector subspace of $V \otimes W$ in general. Try adding two elements together!
2. Consider the case where $V = 0$: then $V \otimes W = 0$ as well.

Comment: About 1, I thought that if I have a basis of both spaces V, W, then the tensored basisvectors form a basis of the tensorproduct space. Is this incorrect? I thought the statement follows from that. Furthermore, about 2, how is this an obstruction?

Comment: Wait, I don't buy your answer to 2. What if $V=W$, some 1-dimensional v.s., and $\phi_1$ and $\theta_2$ are both multiplication by some nonzero number $r$, and $\theta_1$ and $\phi_2$ are multiplication by $1/r$?

Comment: Pascal, you're right about a basis. But a general vector is a linear combination of basis elements, of course.